# Как infoWindow разместить сбоку от маркера на Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-api, infowindow

По-умолчанию, инфоокно всплывает сверху маркера при клике на него, а можно ли разместить его справа?

Answer (score 0):

[Customizable info windows using the Google Maps JavaScript API](https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window).
Там же ссылки на демо